# Binary Search Tree; Self Organizing Search/Rotation C++

Tags: c++, search, binary-search-tree

For my project I am to create a Self-Organizing Binary Search Tree. I have successfully created the BST but for some reason I can't quite figure out how to implement the Organizing portion.

To be more specific, 
When I perform a search for a value, I am to increment its search count. Once the search count equals the "Thresh hold Value" (set through the constructor) I rotate that searched node up one.

I am confident I can figure out how to perform the rotation but my problem lies with the integer variables **searchCount** and **threshVal**. For some reason, I can't figure out how to get **searchCount** to only increment with the searched value, and reset when I search for a new value

For example:
I have "1 2 3 4 5" in my BST. I perform a search for the value "3", I find it, increment the search count to 1.
Then, I perform another search, this time on the value "5". The **searchCount** variable is then incremented again to 2, when it should be 1 since I searched for a different value.

Here is my *Search* function. It's a big .cpp file so I'll just include the one function.

```
template <typename T>
bool BST<T>::contains(const T& v, BSTNode *&t)
{
    if (t == nullptr)
        return false;
    else if(v < t->data)
        return contains(v, t->left);
    else if(t->data < v)
        return contains(v, t->right);
    else{

        if(t->right == nullptr)
            return true;
        /*
          Problem lies in the following segment, I just added the little
          rotation portion to try and get something to work for testing
          purposes. The problem still lies with threshVal and searchCount
         */
        if (searchCount == threshVal){
            BSTNode *temp = t->right;
            t->right = temp->left;
            temp->left = t;
            t = temp;

            if(t == root)
                searchCount = 0;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

If I need to give y'all more info, or perhaps add the rest of the .cpp file let me know. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you search the internet for "balanced binary tree".  This may be very close to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't add a comment but did you try giving each node its own int count?

example:

```
struct treeNode
    {
        treeNode* left;
        treeNode* right;
        T data;
        treeNode() {left = NULL; right = NULL;};
        treeNode(const T&v, treeNode* l, treeNode* r){data = v; left = l;  right = r;};
int count = 0;
    };
```

Then incrementing that node's individual count when a search is conducted?

Comment: Then when 5 is searched and found you increment the node's count. When that count is equal to whatever the count threshold is, then rotate it.